# Generic getter and setter methods

Tags: java, generics, setter, getter, getter-setter

I am trying to write an abstract class. This class is going to be a Field. There will be different types of fields which will need to extend the field class and write its own setter class. For example....There will be a String Field and an Integer Field.

String Field will need to extend the Field class but must have it's own `setValue` and `getValue` method which has a String variable to set and return. Number Field must do the same with Integer.

I think the best way is to have a Generic Type set Value in the super class but I am not sure how to do about this. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: do little google , before post questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your super class generic:

```
public abstract class Field<T>{
  private T value;

  public void setValue(T value){
     this.value = value;
  }

  public T getValue(){
     return value;
  }
}
```

if you now extend it like:

```
public class StringField extends Field<String>{
   //nothing to do here.
}
```

you are already done.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
public abstract class Field<T> {
    private T value;
    // + constructor(s)
    public T get() {
        return value;
    }
    public void set(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class StringField extends Field<String>{}
public class IntField extends Field<Integer>{}
```

You might want to add constructors such as `Field(T value)` and `StringField(String s)`.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a really good practice to get acquainted with generics. Now there are a bunch of tutorials available so I'll try to explain a little bit what is happening and then I'll urge you too look up a few of them.

Basically you can think of generics as a way to tell your object during runtime which type(s) it will have, this is the type within the `<` and `>`.

So `ArrayList<String>` will be an ArrayList containing the type `String`. So going back to what you wan't to do is make your `Field` class generic.

This is easily accomplished with:

```
public class Field<T> {
    private T field;
}
```

Now when you create an instance of your Field class, say for a String, you'll simply write:

```
Field<String> f = new Field<>();
```

To write a generic getter with the same type as the type decided during runtime you will have do the following:

```
public class Field<T> {
    private T field;

    public T getField() { return field; }
}
```

I'll leave creating the setter as an excercise for you.

Remember that in this case `T` is a placeholder for the type that `Field` gets during runtime.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who contributed. I have studied Generics but wasn't sure how to fit it into my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Basic implementation

```
public abstract class Field<T> {
    private T value;
    // + constructor(s)
    public T get() {
        return value;
    }
    public void set(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class StringField extends Field<String>{}
public class IntField extends Field<Integer>{}
```

for more details Please visit this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19206-01/816-4178/dynamic-10/index.html) [link2](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/getters-setters.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you've suggested is perfectly reasonable, it would look something like this:

```
public class Field<T extends Object> {

    private T value;

    public Field(final T value) { 
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(final T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Note, I have made this specifically not abstract on purpose. There's no need to use this as a super class unless you actually want to implement extra functionality for the specific field types. So you could define your Sting Fields and Number Fields like this:

```
Field<String> stringField = new Field<String>();
Field<Integer> numberField = new Field<Integer>();
```

Of course, if you do want extra implementations within the typed versions of Field, then make it abstract and define your subclasses as follows:

```
public class StringField extends Field<String> {
    public StringField(final String value) {
        super(value);
    }
}

public class NumberField extends Field<Integer> {
    public NumberField(final Integer value) {
        super(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the `abstract class`?

Comment: Fair question, I'll make my point more clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class MyClass<T>{
  private T field;

  public T getField(){
    return field;
  }

  public void setField(T field){
    this.field = field;
  }
}


public class MyClassWithString extends MyClass<String>{}
```